# Converting '03/11/2019 11:45:00' to hive timestamp

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have dates in the format `'3/20/2019 17:23:00'` or `'2/1/2019 11:44:00'` and they come in as `null` when I specify the type as timestamp in hive. I am trying to convert it to with the following code but I'm not sure if it's not possible or if I'm specifying the pattern incorrectly.

For example one of these date variables is called 'on_dtml'

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(on_dtml, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS'))
```

I wrote the values as string format in one table, defined a second table where they are in timestamp, and now I am trying to write the values from the table where they are stored as string to the second table with the code above. Please help

```
insert into table test_table 
select variable1 string, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(on_dtml, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct pattern is `'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'`:

```
 from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(on_dtml, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'));
```

Read about format patterns here: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) Upper/lower case matters a lot in the pattern.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('3/20/2019 17:23:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'));
```

Result:

```
2019-03-20 17:23:00
```

One more test:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2/1/2019 11:44:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'));
```

Result:

```
2019-02-01 11:44:00
```